# What is precision on prediction given precision of rules

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, precision-recall

I'm new to statistics and have a question about my machine learning method. This method can distinguish between positive/negative examples. The result is a set of rules to define only positive examples.

For each rule I have calculated the precision as follows:

precision = $\frac{\mathrm{TP}}{\mathrm{TP+FP}}$

where:

- $\mathrm{TP}$ = true positives covered by the rule.
- $\mathrm{FP}$ = False positive covered by the rule.

I use the method to predict an unknown example. The example is predicted as deleterious by three independent rules, which have precisions of

1. 30% (a bad rule)
2. 95%
3. 88%

What is the final precision score for the unknown example?

Comment: Welcome to the site and it's an excellent question to ask.  You'll need to help us with what is meant by "95% of precision".  Most likely, this might mean something like "we created a 95% confidence interval that for the true parameter, which was the range [lower, upper]."  That would mean you actually have six numbers: either three upper and three lower limits, or three point estimates and three standard errors or relative margins of error (eg +/- X %).  So maybe edit your question to be a bit more precise on exactly what information you've got.

Comment: @PeterEllis I think OP means that the experiment has binary output.

Comment: The question has been edited since my first comment and we now have a clearer idea of what it is about and my presumption that we had a confidence interval seems to have been completely wrong.  Which is why it's good to clarify!

Answer (score 1):

(This could have been a comment but gets a bit too long).

The "final precision score" seems vaguely defined here.  If you just had three independent experiments trying to measure the same underlying parameter (let's call it "truthness"), you could just pool your results and work out the overall score of $\frac{\sum{TP}}{\sum{TP + FP}}$.  But in fact it looks like you want to compare three independent experiments that are measuring *different* underlying parameters - the truthness as measured by rule 1, by rule 2 and rule 3.  There's no statistical way of judging between the three rules - perhaps rule 1 is the best measure and it's a really bad machine learning method, perhaps rule 3 and 2 are and it's good.  You need some extra (non-statistical) information to judge which of the rules is more useful for you.

Comment: And i can make a consensus prediction, like..
If the precision of Exp 1 = 95% and exp 2 = 95% the final precision is 97,5%.
If final precision is 97,5% and a third experiment have a precision of 95%, The final precision becomes 98,2%, and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not very well asked : when you say "What is the final precision score for the unknown example", I guess you mean what is the final precision score for the method because you cannot calculate precision for one individual (see your formula in your question). 
And if I understand correctly you thus need to define your new method using the three rules. How do you aggregate them to make a prediction ? Majority vote ? When you have defined how to aggregate the three rule, you can use your prediction to recalculate your precision the same way you did for the three rules.